# Apache configured for HSTS, but SSLLabs/Chrome not acknowledging

Tags: security, apache-http-server, ssl, https, headers

I'm setting up a webserver and I've been checking it against SSLLabs and Chrome 31 to make sure the security is up to snuff. However neither Chrome nor SSLLabs seems to believe that strict transport security is enabled for the domain. I can't seem to figure out why. Below are response headers from curl when accessing the site.

```
$curl -I ********.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Apache
Date: Sat, 14 Dec 2013 22:58:27 GMT
Location: https://********.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

$curl -kI https://********.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Date: Sat, 14 Dec 2013 22:59:26 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Dec 2013 04:58:41 GMT
ETag: "422-4ed12d98c43d3"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1058
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains
Content-Type: text/html
```

My Apache Config, as reported by `mod_info`

```
Module Name: mod_headers.c
Content handlers: none
Configuration Phase Participation: Create Directory Config, Merge Directory Configs
Request Phase Participation: Post-Read Request, Fixups, Insert Filters, Insert Errors
Module Directives:
Header - an optional condition, an action, header and value followed by optional env clause
RequestHeader - an action, header and value followed by optional env clause
Current Configuration:
In file: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-********-ssl.conf
   2: <VirtualHost _default_:443>
  30:   Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains"
    : </VirtualHost>
```